# XYZ Layer in OpenLayers has missing tiles

Tags: openlayers-2, tiles, layers, error, tilemill

In OpenLayers I'm having a missing tile problem where it generates a missing link icon and a pink background. I found several threads including [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27668/wrong-tiles-generated-in-openlayers-xyz-layer) one saying to add this code
    `OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function() {this.src = '/img/blank.png';};`

Sorry if this is dumb, but should my blank.png just be a 1px transparent png24? And also where should the img folder go?

Sorry, I've tried 1px, 256px, png24, png8, gif and putting the img folder and/or file in every conceivable place and I'm having no luck. Maybe you'll see something in these screenshots.

I've also tried an image with color to see if I can notice any actual change, so that's why the blank.png file looks red in the Finder thumbnail.

[image: chrome]
[image: code]
[image: file structure]

Comment: you don't need an image - it is just there to force the tile cache to get the 'real' images from Openlayers mobile - http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Open Layers. Could you please paste how this code should read? `OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function() {this.src = '/img/blank.png';};`

Answer (score 5):

Woohoo! Figured it out. [This thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/how-to-avoid-pink-tiles-when-db-view-table-is-empty) had the solution to change the CSS rather than the JS.

```
.olImageLoadError { 
    /* when OL encounters a 404, don't display the pink image */
    display: none !important;
}
```

[This help article](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/TroubleshootingTips) was helpful too, but I have not idea how to tell TileMill/MapBox to generate blank tiles rather than missing tiles. I'll get there someday.

Comment: TileMill will skip empty tiles; in map clients there's always a way to handle 404s somewhat gracefully and skipping tiles with no data is much more performant than rendering blank tiles everywhere.

Comment: Agreed. Any ideas are most surely welcome :) I haven't been able to figure it out so far.